# How to perform google search with python without 429 error (too many requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search

```py
from googlesearch import search

def get_results(req):
    response = search(req, num_results=10, proxy='3.8.203.84:3128')
    links = []
    for result in response:
        links.append(result)

    return links


for i in range(100):
    print(get_results('google'))
```

I tried to use proxy and ratelimits. With proxy problem doesn't disappear and with ratelimits it is working a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Google has rate limiting which avoid too many requests spamming their servers and overloading their services, this is why you get such error.
What I would suggest is sleeping between requests.

You can use:

```
import time

time.sleep(<n_seconds>)
```

so your code would look like:

```
import time
for i in range(100): 
    print(get_results('google'))
    time.sleep(1)
```

which will sleep you program for 1 second between requests.

There are more advanced/smarted ways to do this using libraries like https://pypi.org/project/limit/ but for now I would try the sleep method and see if it works and as you get more advanced you can make it better.